# Modify a column, to get rid of html surrounding an ID

Tags: sql, regex, t-sql, iframe

I have a table and one of the columns contains html for an iFrame & within it an external video, specifically it's like

```
<iframe src="http://host.com/videos/ID" otherattributes...></iframe>.
```

I need to update the current column or create a new one (doesn't matter) so what I have is just the ID of that video, I know I could use a regex for it but I'm really weak with it.
perhaps so it find the content that is within literal characters: [videos/] and the upcoming ["] which comes right after the ID but I'm unsure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  use [CHARINDEX()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) function:

```
update T SET
   VideoID=SUBSTRING(descr,
          charindex('/videos/',descr)+LEN('/videos/'),
          charindex('"',descr,charindex('/videos/',descr)+LEN('/videos/'))
          -(charindex('/videos/',descr)+LEN('/videos/')))
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21e16/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

This should work, assuming the text `videos/` doesn't appear anywhere else in the html.

```
update htmltable 
set id = SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(html, 
                          CHARINDEX('videos/', html) + 7, 
                          LEN(html)
                          ), 
                 0, 
                 CHARINDEX('"', SUBSTRING(html, 
                                          CHARINDEX('videos/', html) + 7, 
                                          LEN(html)
                                         )
                          )
                )
```

This updates a field named `otherfield` in table `htmltable` where the id in the url is '123'.  It's pretty ugly code, but SQL Server has limited string functions.

If you have any control over the table structure, I would suggest you make some changes.  The video ID should be stored in its own column, separate from the rest of the url.  Then when you need to retrieve the url, you would concatenate the two parts to get the whole url.  That would be much more maintainable.

Comment: The html part is identical across all of them, what I want to do is to separate the IDs from the html, and create another table of "video providers" where I'll store providerid & name, asigning the provider id as a FK on the video id table, using the provider ID I'll build the link using a hidden-'script' html on the client side.

Comment: Got it.  I've updated my query.  It's probably a crapshoot between mine and valex's answer.  I don't think there's a way to do it that won't be ugly.